# Understanding Keyboard Mapping

Tags: linux, keyboard

I was reading the man pages on `find` when I came across the part that says one can re-program the keyboard bindings. This got my interest.

When I looked into the subject, and went to see my own Linux key bindings (using `dumpkeys`), I wanted to give it a try and test it.
I took the (logical) line that reads:

```
keycode  83 = KP_Period       
altgr   control keycode  83 = Boot
```

According to the lines: If I hit <kbd>RIGHT ALT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> (keypad dot/period), the driver sends boot signal and the system should go into boot process.

And this did NOT happen.

What am I missing here?